# How to export image to Google Classroom?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-classroom

Like `Facebook` or `Twitter` I need to export image within my iOS app to `Google Classroom`. I went through some documentation provided by Google but I couldn't find any kind of SDK. Is google provided any kind of iOS SDK for `Google Classroom` or do we need to use rest API instead of SDK?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should have the google classroom application installed on your ios device.
Next, On your ios device when you select the option to export you should see the google classroom option in the list, and if you don't see that option just select more at the end, and there you should have it.
[see the image here for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGKVU.jpg)

Comment: No. Actually I want to export image within my iOS app and I want to integrate google classroom with my application.